# LDAP/JNDI Connection Issue : Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

In my java project, I need to access LDAP And I am doing it using the below code.

```
    public static LdapContext openConnection() throws AxisFault,Exception {
        if (ctxGC == null) {
            ctxGC = getCtxGC();
        }
        return ctxGC;
    }

    private static LdapContext getCtxGC() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LdapContext context = null;
        Map<String, String> map = LDAPUtility.getLDAPParameters();
        String user = map.get("userName");
        String pass = map.get("password");
        String ldapHost = map.get("hostName");
        String domain = map.get("domain");

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapHost);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user + "@" + domain);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);

        try {
            context = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
            log.debug("LDAP context initialized successfully !");
            return context;
        } catch (NamingException nex) {
            log.error("Exception occured", nex);
        }
        return context;
    }
```

It was working correctly but suddenly started to throw the below error.

```
    javax.naming.NoInitialContextException","exception_message":"Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial","stacktrace":"javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: Maybe a failure at LDAPUtility.getLDAPParameters();?

Comment: No, That is fine I have checked it by logging it. @jwilleke.